# How to databind alt tag in ASP.NET hyperlink control?

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, alt

I have this tag: `alt='<%# Eval("ImageDesc") %>'`  inside a DataList control

When I view the page in my browser the alt tag is always empty: `alt=""`

Maybe this is because the alt tag is not supported by the hyperlink control? How can I databind the alt tag?

------- this is the exact code

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="linkQuoteImage" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" ImageUrl='<%# "/images/"+Eval("ImageFile").ToString().Replace("/","/tmb/") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# "~/Quotes/"+Eval("SlugText") %>' alt='<%# Eval("ImageDesc") %>' Font-Underline="False" ForeColor="#333333"></asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: So you are trying to add the alt property to an image inside the hyperlink. Please, show us the markup of these controls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if in the aspx page

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="linkQuoteImage" runat="server">Text for image alt</asp:HyperLink>
```

If in the code behind just do linkQuoteImage.Text = "Text for image alt" -- The text you need in the alt

Comment: thanks! this is the most simple and effective solution

Answer (score 3):

Really, the Hyperlink does not have the `alt` property. Use Tooltip instead, if this is what want:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lnkTest" runat="server" ToolTip='<%# Eval("Data") %>'>'<%# Eval("OtherData")%>'</asp:HyperLink>
```

The `alt` property is used in a `<img>` tag to show a replace text when the image is not found. Also, the text is shown as a tooltip in some browsers. If you want to show a tooltip, use the HTML `title` property, which can be obtained by using the `Tooltip` ASP.Net property.

Comment: No, I don't need a tooltip, I need the alt tag for SEO. And the Hyperlink control inludes the <img> tag so it should be possible.

Answer (score 3):

alt attribute is used in hyperlink when we are using basic html

but in case of u r using asp.net hyperlink control alt property is replaced by ToolTip use this instead

replace
alt='<%# Eval("ImageDesc") %>'  by   ToolTip='<%# Eval("ImageDesc") %>'

Comment: I don't need the tooltip property, I need the alt tag for SEO

Answer (score 1):

Is your `<asp:HyperLink>` control inside of some control like a Repeater?

This code works for me.

Front end:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptTest" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="testLink" runat="server" alt='<%# Eval("ImageDesc") %>'>This is a link</asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Back end:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var images = new List<ImageData>
    {
        new ImageData { ImageDesc = "test" },
        new ImageData { ImageDesc = "test2" }
    };
    rptTest.DataSource = images;
    rptTest.DataBind();
}
```

...

```
public class ImageData
{
    public string ImageDesc { get; set; }
}
```

If you aren't using a control that has the `Eval` method available, then you'll need to add the property differently.  I would recommend just setting it in the code-behind.

Front end:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="testLink" runat="server">This is a link</asp:HyperLink>
```

Back end:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (testLink.Attributes["alt"] == null)
    {
        testLink.Attributes.Add("alt", "test");
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a datalist control, and eval works on all hyperlink properties, Text, NavigationLink, ...except the alt tag which is not filled by the Eval function.

Comment: @MarioM the code I provided that works with a repeater also works with a DataList.  I think your problem lies elsewhere.  It's hard to diagnose much more than that.  Can you edit your post to provide more code?  Seeing the DataList itself, as well as the code where you're binding data to it, would be helpful.

Comment: @MarioM have you made sure the spelling of `ImageDesc` in your Eval call matches the spelling of the property you're trying to access on the object?

Comment: The same Eval in a label control displays the text correctly. So the names are ok. I have included the exact line of code which I have